# Schroedinger's property: PHP class property name with `__get()` returns value, but also "doesn't exist" error

Tags: php

I have a class, with a protected property, in PHP 7.3.  The class has a `__get()` method set up to return the properties, but not allow them to be altered.  Pretty basic:

```
Class myClass {
protected $name;

...

public function __get( $prop ) {
    if ( isset( $this->$prop ) ) {
        return $this->$prop;
    } else {
        error_log( "Call to nonexistent '$prop' property of " . __CLASS__ . " class" )
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

I have a function that sorts arrays and objects.  Within that code, I have a little bit that chooses the value to sort on.  If it's an array, grab that element.  If it's an object, look for a function, and if no function, look for a property:

```
$ae = is_array( $a ) ? $a[ $arg ] :
    ( is_callable( [$a, $arg] ) ? $a->$arg() :
    $a->$arg );
```

So I ran a test, to call up one of the read-only properties of an object -- "name".

If I call this directly, `$myObj->name` returns a value as expected.

If I pass it into the sorting function, with `$a = $myObj` and `$arg = "name"`, I **do** get the value back, (that is, it sorts properly), but I also get the error that the property doesn't exist.

`Call to nonexistent 'name' property of myClass class`

So... The "variable variable" property name is working fine, and passing through the `__get()` function as I would expect, but it is still pinging the error.  Schroedinger's property both exists and doesn't exist.  It's triggering both branches of the `if()` clause in the `__get()`.

NOTE: I broke the sorting code over multiple lines to pinpoint the error. It is definitely on the third line -- the `$a->$arg`.  If I change it to `( $a->$arg ?? null )` it gives the exact same error.  Remember: it *is* returning the value; but simultaneously logging an error that there is no such value.

What is going on here?  How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce (PHP 7.4). Are you sure it sorts? If it's just a few elements it may be due to chance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will isset() return false if I assign NULL to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985890/will-isset-return-false-if-i-assign-null-to-a-variable)

Comment: @yivi That is what was happening. I figured this out yesterday, but SO doesn’t let me accept my own answer until tomorrow

Comment: It would be better to accept the duplicate, IMO, so the information is appropriately linked. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is what happened:  The bug was only firing for *some* of the entries while sorting, not all of them.  (The log had a ton of these errors, so it wasn't obvious just from looking.)

Look at the `__get()` code:

```
public function __get( $prop ) {
    if ( isset( $this->$prop ) ) {
        return $this->$prop;
    } else {
        error_log( "Call to nonexistent '$prop' property of " . __CLASS__ . " class" )
        return null;
    }
}
```

Some of the data coming from the database had blank fields, which came across as Null to the code.  `isset( null )` is a false-y value, so the `else` clause of the If was firing on those entries.

The fix?  Don't check `isset()`, check `property_exists()`.

```
public function __get( $prop ) {
    if ( property_exists( $this, $prop ) ) {
...
```